# Split string by values and fill JSON with it (NiFi)

Tags: json, apache-nifi, jolt

I've a JSON:

```json
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "status": 0
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "status": 0
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "status": 1
  }
]
```

And I've an attribute `task-ids`. It's a string with comma separated values. For example it can be: `500, 501, 502`, or `765, 780, 790` or `10, 11, 12` etc. **Numbers can be completely random, but their order and amount matches with order and amount of json objects.** I mean first element from string is always should go to the first object in json, second to second, etc. For the first case `500` should go to object with `id` = 1, 501 to 2, 502 to 3. Order in this string equals to order of objects. So I expect this:

```json
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "status": 0,
    "taskId": 500
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "status": 0,
    "taskId": 501
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "status": 1,
    "taskId": 502
  }
]
```

My task is: split string from an attribute and fill source JSON by these values from string. Order is maintained. First element from an attribute should go to first element of JSON, etc.

I wrote simple Groovy script for this task, but maybe there is another option to solve this task (without using scripts)?

```php
def numbersString = flowFile.getAttribute("task-ids");
def numbersArray = numbersString.split(',').collect { it as Integer }

for (int i = 0; i < numbersArray.size(); i++) {
    jsonArray[i].taskId = numbersArray[i]
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might use ***intSum*** function within a **modify** transformation such as

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "taskId": "=intSum(@(1,id),499)"
      }
    }
  }
]
```

the ***demo*** on the site http://jolt-demo.appspot.com/ is :

[image]

Comment: Thanks! But it will not work if `task-ids` will have another values (not 500, 501, 502). It's a dynamic property and stores comma separated values as string and it's always different.

Comment: Hi @fujidaon , then make the case clearer for me by adding more sample values or the describing the exact rule please.

Comment: Updated, is it better now?

Comment: How do you keep `task-ids` attribute within your flow, how you pass to an attribute of what processor ? @fujidaon